# Finding and setting up wifi in FreeBSD 12.0

Tags: wifi, freebsd

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100S 14'' IBR-14'' Intel Celeron CPU  N3060  @ 1.60GHz, 32GB SSD, 4GB RAM, but I am both at a loss what wifi I have there, as there are several different generations, and how to find which driver I have to use in FreeBSD.

How to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find what kernel wifi the driver to use, do:

```
$sysctl net.wlan.devices 
net.wlan.devices: iwm0
```

So we know now we have to use iwm0.

You can also find the corresponding hardware doing:

```
$ pciconf -lv iwm0
iwm0@pci0:2:0:0:    class=0x028000 card=0x82708086 chip=0x08b48086 rev=0x93 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = 'Wireless 3160'
    class      = network
```

So now we know it is a model with an Intel Wireless AC, and the `iwm0`; which are very good news, as this model was sold to me as capable of doing bgn, and not 802.11n AC.

While in the past the Intel 3160AC driver had to be compiled, nowadays, it is already supported by the default kernel.

Now to set it up, we will load the module, the firmware and the supported wifi authentication protocols in `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
legal.intel.license_ack=1
if_iwm_load="YES"
iwm3160fw_load="YES"
wlan_wep_load="YES"
wlan_ccmp_load="YES"
wlan_tkip_load="YES"
```

Also in `/etc/rc.conf`, will define the `wpa_supplicant`, DHCP client, activate the interface and define the country as PT for it to transmit in a stronger frequency more appropriate for my country:

```
wpa_supplicant_enable="YES"
synchronous_dhclient="YES"
wlans_iwm0="wlan0"
create_args_wlan0="country PT"
```

Now search for `wpa_config` and install it:

```
#pkg search wpa_config
wpa_gui-2.6                    Qt-based frontend for wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant-2.6             Supplicant (client) for WPA/802.1x protocols
#pkg install wpa_gui wpa_supplicant
```

Edit now `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
 ssid="my_ssid"
 priority=146
 scan_ssid=1
 psk="wifipassword"
}
```

Upon restarting, you can see the lines, or later with `dmesg`.

```
iwm0: hw rev 0x160, fw ver 17.352738.0, address f4:06:69:xx:xx:xx
wlan0: Ethernet address: f4:06:69:xx:xx:xx
iwm0: iwm_update_edca: called
iwm0: iwm_update_edca: called
wlan0: link state changed to UP
```

We have now wifi connectivity, IP address and Internet connectivity.

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    ether f4:06:69:xx:xx:xx
    inet 192.168.1.9 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255 
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: IEEE 802.11 Wireless Ethernet OFDM/54Mbps mode 11g
    status: associated
    ssid xxxx channel 13 (2472 MHz 11g) bssid 30:b5:c2:xx:xx:xx
    regdomain ETSI country PT authmode WPA2/802.11i privacy ON
    deftxkey UNDEF AES-CCM 2:128-bit AES-CCM 3:128-bit txpower 30 bmiss 10
    scanvalid 60 protmode CTS wme roaming MANUAL
    groups: wlan
```

Finally for configuring it graphically, you can use `wpa_gui` ; if using Lumina you can also install `pcbsd-utils` to have the wifi icon on the tray.

To list for the available SSIDs in the command line do:

```
#ifconfig wlan0 list scan
SSID/MESH ID    BSSID              CHAN RATE    S:N     INT CAPS
MEO-1608CD      c4:ea:1d:16:08:cd    1   54M  -87:-96   100 EP   RSN      HTCAP WPS WPA WME
MEO-WiFi        c6:ea:1d:16:08:ce    1   54M  -89:-96   100 ES   HTCAP WME
Vodafone-11...  9c:97:26:11:ad:10    1   54M  -70:-96   100 EP   RSN HTCAP WPS WPA WME
NOS-14F0        f0:f2:49:99:14:f8   12   54M  -88:-96   100 EPS  WPS HTCAP WPA RSN WME BSSLOAD
NOS_WIFI_Fon    bc:4d:fb:53:65:d9   12   54M  -88:-96   100 ES   HTCAP WME BSSLOAD
xxxx            30:b5:c2:xx:xx:xx   13   54M  -44:-96   100 EPS  RSN HTCAP WME
xxxxx           30:b5:c2:xx:xx:xx   36   54M  -50:-96   100 EP   RSN HTCAP VHTCAP VHTOPMODE WME
MEO-A8E087-5G   e2:b9:e5:a8:e0:87   60   54M  -78:-96   100 EP   RSN HTCAP VHTCAP VHTOPMODE VHTPWRENV WPS WPA WME
oLi oNe         2c:9d:1e:d3:22:c0  124   54M  -75:-96    98 EP   RSN BSSLOAD HTCAP VHTCAP VHTOPMODE VHTPWRENV WPS WPA WME
```

Further reading: FreeBSD Handbok [30.3. Wireless Networking](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html)